# How to find if an int contains a leading 0 in c++

Tags: c++, string, oop, integer, number-formatting

So i know in c++ leading 0s in ints are still there and used, but when you print it out it gets rid of the 0, so I want to know if there is a way to check if there is a leading 0 if so when printing it out to display it? or if there is a way I can manually check the first digit of the int and check if its == 0, and I can add in a 0 when printing out?
For my case, the int will always be 2 digits only. So the int could be `00` or `01`
or `55`.

e.g

```
int main()
{
  int b = 01;
  std::cout << b << "\n"; // This should print 01 not 1
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"So i know in c++ leading 0s in ints are still there and used"_ what do you mean?

Comment: `int b = 01;` is the same as `int b = 1;` (except that `01` uses octal representation, and the later decimal notation).

Answer (score 1):

Integers are stored as binary. I suppose you are talking about displaying integers on your screen. Don't confuse internal representation with how integers are displayed. To display with leading zeros you can use `std::setw` in combination with `std::setfill`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct zero_padded {
    unsigned value;
    unsigned width = 2;    
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const zero_padded& zp){
    return out << std::setw(zp.width) << std::setfill('0') << zp.value;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << zero_padded{25} << "\n";
  std::cout << zero_padded{5} << "\n";
  std::cout << zero_padded{0} << "\n";
  std::cout << zero_padded{25,4} << "\n";
  std::cout << zero_padded{5,4} << "\n";
  std::cout << zero_padded{0,4} << "\n";    
}
```

Output:

```
25
05
00
0025
0005
0000
```

Comment: so say I have a class member of int that always will store 2 digits only e.g 11 , 02, 05, 13 etc how can I without hard coding it be able to get that int member and print it out, without it getting rid of a trialing 0 so e.g 02 should output 02 not just 2, but e.g 13 should just display 13, not 03.

Comment: @xanderdaily101 you cant have a int member that stores two decimal digits always (at least not out of the box, and if you wrote some code to do it you need to show it). Anyhow this answer shows how you can print an integer with desired width

Comment: Sorry yeah i forgot to mention I have done a check to make sure digit is only 2 digits.